# MongoDB : How to find multiple documents and update at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have mongo DB and I am using C#.Net to interact with mongo db. C# API has methods for finding a **single** document and updating it at the same time. For example `FindOneAndUpdateAsync`.
However I couldn't find any method to find multiple documents and update them at the same time asynchronously.

The code below finding and processing each document asynchronously. How do I also update that document at the same time?

```
    public async Task<IList<IDictionary<string, string>>> DoWork()
    {
        var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("units");
        var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = filterBuilder.Ne<string>("status", "INIT") &
            (filterBuilder.Exists("isDone", false) |
            filterBuilder.Eq<bool>("isDone", false));

        // I want to pass this update filter to update the document. But not sure how
        var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
           .CurrentDate("startTime");

        var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("startTime");

        var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
            .Include("_id")                
            .Include("fileName");  // for bravity i have removed other projection elements

        var output = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

        // How do i pass update filter and update the document at the same time?? 
        await collection
            .Find(filter)
            .Sort(sort)
            .Project(projection)                
            .ForEachAsync((unit) =>
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Recurse(unit, dictionary);
                output.Add(dictionary);
            });

        return output.Count > 0 ? output : null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't exist in the mongo .Net api see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709849/how-to-do-findall-in-the-new-mongo-c-sharp-driver-and-make-it-synchronous).

Just use a combination of **Find** and **UpdateManyAsync**.

Comment: I was looking for how to do it? Do I write it in one command or 2 separate calls?

Comment: Two separate calls: flow should be use find to retrieve your documents, manipulate the attributes on the documents as necessary, use UpdateMany to save them all. Take a look at the mongo api docs for exact examples of how to use those calls.